# Pentaho 6 - cannot download or upload saiku pivots in Pentaho User Console (PUC)

Tags: download, pentaho, saiku

I want to download the pivots and other user saved files in the PUC to move it to another server.

When I download them, I only get a zip file containing an exportManifest.xml file. Or even folders but the ".saiku" files are missing.

Answer (score 1):

This is a known problem in Pentaho.

**Fix for downloading:**

Edit `\biserver-ce\pentaho-solutions\system\ImportHandlerMimeTypeDefinitions.xml`

Insert a tag `<extension>saiku</extension>` inside the tag `<MimeTypeDefinition mimeType="text/xml">`.

Then after a restart of BIServer downloads will include *.saiku

But then upload will not work.

**Fix for uploading:**

Edit `\biserver-ce/pentaho-solutions/system/importExport.xml`

Insert a tag `<entry key="saiku" value-ref="streamConverter"/>` at around line 53.

Then after a restart of BIServer uploads will include *.saiku

More details:

- https://forums.pentaho.com/threads/230756-Downloading-saiku-files
- https://jira.pentaho.com/browse/BISERVER-11283